# ErrorDocument 404 for a multi-lingual site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multilingual, errordocument

I'm facing a little problem which is causing a conflict in my website. when I'm for example on this page `/en/pagenotexists/`, how can I simply refer to `/en/404.php`?

I'm using the following directive in my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I tried this solution but didn't work at all:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/ /$1/404.php [R=404,L]
```

Comment: What does the server do when you request **/en/pagenotexists/** ?

Comment: thanks for your message. Let's say the default language is "fr", if i request "/en/pagenotexists/" the page will load in french, and i would like it to be displayed in english

Comment: Do you mean "if you request **/en/notexist** it should load **/en/404.php** and **/fr/notexist** should load **/fr/404.php** ?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the content of lang specific `404.php` with correct `404` status code you can use this internal rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/ $1/404.php [L]
```

Then have your `/en/404.php` as this:

```
<?php
// return correct 404 status code
http_response_code(404);

// rest of the 404 handler content
?>
```

Comment: Oh cool, i'll try it out :) did you mean to omit the leading slash before $1? Thanks

Comment: You can put leading slash before `$1` but that won't make any difference if .htaccess is in site root.

Comment: yes, it worked well, thanks :) but i'm facing now another related problem, i'll try to solve it and I'll let you know if I don't manage to ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the R=404 :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/ /$1/404.php [R,L]
```

Otherwise the rule will redirect the request to the default  404 page instead of rule's destination.

Comment: what you gave me didn't work, but it works with this directive: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}) /$1/error-404/ [QSA,L]` (removing the slash and using QSL)!

But if i remove the R=404, i will prevent apache from sending the 404 headers, right?

Comment: Yes that's true. You will not be able to receive the 404 header but instead you will receive 302 response.

Comment: And doesn't it matter not to receive 404 headers? :)